# What's the better verb to use for New Year's resolution?

Tags: word-choice

Do you say

My New Year's resolution always breaks in the first month, or always collapses in the first month?

Comment: Personally, I would say *My New Year's resolutions **never last more than** a month*

Answer (score 1):

Because a New Year's resolution isn't an actual physical object, you wouldn't say "breaks" or "collapses". Instead, you might say "I always break my New Year's resolution within the first month." Because using the work "break" in this sense is a metaphorical breaking. It's the same way you would use "break" in the phrase "break a promise", where you also wouldn't say "my promise breaks".

Comment: But you could say *my promise was broken*. So, I don't think there's a *syntactical* reason to not say *my promise breaks*. It's just, arbitrarily, something we don't say. However, given this, the explanation of it being a physical object isn't sufficient.

Comment: I agree that it is a syntactical reason, but in my answer I was likening a new years resolution to a promise, to say that it followed the same syntactical conventions as the word promise does. I also brought up the whole physical object thing to explain why it would seem awkward in that sentence to use "my new year's resolution was broken"